# multiple scripts files via ajax or combined all?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Content from my site gets changed via ajax. Each page its a ajax request.

Right now each page from my site has some sort of jquery/javascript functions to handle any event require for that page. Each page has their own javascript loaded by getscript and its cached so the javascript is only request when the user visits that page.

My question is it better to load each javascript on request(their cached) or to just put all the javascript functions in one big file and load it once?

Comment: Can you show is an example of your code, or what differs between each one? It might be the case that you can combine the scripts not just concatenate them.

Comment: ok hold on il try to put it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: well it would take a while to put this on jsfiddle but pretty much theres a main.js that just handles the menu interactions and each time you click on a link on the menu it calls a ajax request changes the content from a div and it calls getscript to get the corresponding .js file for that page.

Inside the corresponding .js file thers just some click and form handlers but they vary from page to page

Answer (score 0):

In follow to copy all js from separate page into one - three files.This will reduce the page load and improve page rendering, catching.

Answer (score 0):

I read once on the blog of one of the authors of one of the main javascript script loader libraries (Can't remember which one, and can't find the link) that in the vast majority of cases concatenating everything into one file and including it on each page is the most efficient way to deliver your scripts. Thinking about using somekind of asynchronous loading when all you have are 3 pages is probably over-optimising.